Can I claim the equipment cost as expenditure of my (small) business?
I am using freetaxUSA, but I am not seeing the result that I want, or maybe I am misunderstanding something.
I want to claim the cost of my GoPro as my business expense for my YouTube channel. I also want to claim 50% of the cost of my phone (bought last year) as my business expense since I use my mobile to develop and test mobile Apps, but I can't seem to find the right category where these expenses should go.
I can find a depreciation section that FreeTaxUSA offers but there is no expense section. My question is, can I claim these equipment costs towards my business expenses (write offs) and how do they affect my overall taxes?

I don't know FreeTaxUSA, but Schedule C line 27a is the sum of 'other expenses' which are listed in part V (line 48).

@HartCO Item 18 is what the business expenses should be but there is no provision in the software to enter assets as such (only depreciation) so I am not sure if we can enter 'assets' into business expenses.

Note that you mainly be able to claim business expenses as offset against business income. Is your YouTube channel producing enough income for this to help.l, or should it be treated as hobby income?

You can expense this asset into the first year, and probably should rather than trying to deal with depreciation...

@keshlam that's what I think it should be but as I said, I do not see the section for "Assets" (I only see deprecations section which does allow to enter the asset but that asset is not added to business expense). My YouTube channel was making money till they banned monetization it. But I have other ad reviews though from other websites.

It's not assets, since you're expensing it. You're saying it has no resale value so its asset value is zero. It's just a cost of doing business.

I'm not familiar with the software, but have you tried adding them in the asset section and claiming Sec. 179 depreciation? That's the right way to go, IMHO.

@littleadv: Agreed, that's really the right answer. "The object of the game is to be as honest and accurate as the law allows." (I am coming to hate this keyboard... )

You enter the asset if you're going to depreciate it, but under $2500 items can be expensed, so you aren't entering the asset at all, just noting it in other expenses.

@littleadv There is no asset section :) So, I am not sure how it is supposed to go. Common sense tells me that it should be an expense because there is no way I can provide IT solutoins without a lapop and without mobile which I use for testing the App. Depreciation section has original value but that is not added to 'expense'. I am trying to use a different software now just to see how the other one works.

The problem is not whether it should be, but how to report it. May be spend a few bucks on a better tax software? You get what you pay for

@HartCO: section 179 is called expensing but treated effectively as very fast depreciation; like normal(?) depreciation it goes on 4562 and comes out on Schedule C line 13: "Depreciation and section 179 expense deduction"

@littleadv that's my assessment as well. I did not know if it is cheap, it may not be that good.

@dave_thompson_085 Expensing of business property under the de minimis safe harbor threshold (currently $2500) would actually record the asset purchase as a business expense. Separate from Section 179 or 100% bonus depreciation. If resale of the asset is a consideration then the 100% bonus depreciation is likely best from tax-perspective, but fairly trivial difference on such low cost items.

@dave_thompson_085 The biggest difference for a low-value item is if you treat it as an asset and take a Section 179 deduction, you have to track it over its useful life, and it's subject to recapture if, e.g., the business closes. If you expense, it's one and done.

Just to clarify, I am not talking about section 179 (write off expenses), I am simply asking for regular business costs like, iPhone, Android Phone, laptop for building and testing Apps (which should count towards business cost but I do not see that cost adding up in FreeTaxUSA)
